# Remove "AM" and "PM" Suffix on screenshots

Tags: macos, screen-capture

When I take a screenshot I have the default file format as "Screen Shot 2014-05-29 at 4.24.34 pm".
Is there anyway to remove the AM and PM from the end? For what I do it is very annoying to have this sort the screenshots out of order

I'm going to guess no since it's just grabbing the system time but if anyone could help that'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Open your System Preferences

- Language & Region
- Check the 24 hr box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite

Please note there are two different locations in your time settings.

The one that is located on the 3rd tab "Clock" does NOT change the format of your screen shots:

[image]
Select the 1st tab "Date & Time", then select the "Open Language & Region" button on this page. Then, check the "Time Format [checkbox] 24-Hour Time"

This should fix your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do that for screenshot but not change the time format in e.g. top status bar, check out the solution at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353015/133626

Steps quoted from the above link:

> **System Preferences** → **Language & Region**, then click **Advanced**..., choose the **Times** tab and for the Medium format click the hour dropdown and switch it from **1-12** to **00-23** and delete the AM/PM element.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This is what's called a "link only" answer is frowned-upon on this site.  Answers should be self-contained, even to other answers on this site.  You risk receiving downvotes that will impact your site reputation.  Please see [answer] for important info on providing answers here.

Comment: @fsb, thanks for your reminder. I've added the core answer to the question.